# UWP Failed to assign to property error in custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a custom control `LineChart`. Code in xaml.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeProperty", typeof(Brush), typeof(LineChart), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(),
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsChanged)));

public Brush Stroke
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StrokeProperty, value); }
}
```

In view model class:

```
public Brush Abc
{
    get { return new SolidColorBrush(new Color() {A = 123, B = 123, G = 23, R = 12 } ); }
}
```

In other page:

```
<controls:LineChart  Stroke="{Binding Abc}" />
```

All works fine with static line of code `Stroke="Green"`, but when I use `Binding`, program crushed with error:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with
>   this error code could not be found.
>
> Failed to assign to property
>   CurrencyExchangeUniversal.App.Controls.LineChart.Stroke'. [Line: 102
>   Position: 41]    at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation
>   componentResourceLocation)    at
>   CurrencyExchangeUniversal.App.View.NationalBankPage.InitializeComponent()
>   at CurrencyExchangeUniversal.App.View.NationalBankPage..ctor()

Comment: What is the type of Abc?

Comment: Added code for `Abc`

Comment: Seems like Binding is proper. Check OnItemsChanged method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your `DependencyProperty.Register` call. The first argument value should be `"Stroke"`, not `"StrokeProperty"`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Stroke", typeof(Brush), typeof(LineChart), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(),
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsChanged)));
```

Comment: One problem on StackOverflow that happens to me way too often: I did not make the same mistake as the asker, and I still have the same problem. Since this question is "replied" I don't seem to find a solution now :(