# MVVM ItemTemplate with custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, itemtemplate

I'm following this tutorial on how to use a ListView ItemTemplate to display a list of person : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

I understood the general concept but I am stuck on one point.

Here is the ItemTemplate sample :

```
    <Grid>
            <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource"={Binding MyPersonsList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                                            <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=")" />
                                    </WrapPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

What I cannot understand, is how to replace the TextBlocks with a custom control like this :

```
    <Grid>
            <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource"={Binding MyPersonsList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                            <MyPersonDisplayer Person="{Binding ???}"/>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

How to tell the template I want to set the `MyPersonDisplayer` control property `Person` with the source item ?

---

EDIT :

I tried to add only `Person={Binding}`, but it displays me this error.

[image: CompilError]

Comment: Try it with `<MyPersonDisplayer Person="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: @lokusking I tried, but I have a compilation error. See my edit.

Comment: Remove the textblock. Only one child is supported

Comment: It didn't change anything. Plus, there is only one child in the DataTemplate : the grid (which contains multiple childs)

Comment: Can you provide the code for MenuItemView? XML & .cs

Answer (score 1):

I think it might have problem about the implementation `MenuItemViewModel` **property** in `MenuItemView` **class**. Do you have implement the `MenuItemViewModel` **property** as **DependencyProperty**? Maybe you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259613/uwp-failed-to-assign-to-property-error-in-custom-control).